# Lower index of binomial coefficient becoming negative upon solving

Tags: binomial-coefficients, negative-binomial

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtM8U.png)

While solving this question by using the property: r <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub> = n <sup>n-1</sup>C<sub>r-1</sub>

The value of lower index becomes negative which is invalid

How do I proceed?

Comment: At $r=0, r\ ^nC_r$ is obviously zero.

Comment: @player3236 but after substitution of the RHS into the summation, lower index does become negative right?

Comment: It is common to define $\binom{n}{k}$ to equal zero (*rather than undefined*) in the case of $k$ not equal to a non-negative integer.  You have as a result $\binom{n}{-1}=0$ and there is no issue here.  "*There are no subsets of size $-1$ from a set of size $n$*"

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh ok thanks a lot

Comment: The other way of correcting/justifying this is by specifying that the identity in question should only be considered for the case that $r$ is a positive integer and avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: As for the question you linked, without adjusting the CSS it was impossible to read (*black text on a transparent image superimposed over a black background*).  Be more careful of that as someone who isn't tech-savvy wouldn't be able to read it.  You can note that $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{10} r\binom{20}{r} = \sum\limits_{r=1}^{10}r\binom{20}{r}$ by simply removing the first term in the sum since it is equal to zero to avoid the issue.