# Find the sum $1\times 2 _nC_1+2 \times 3 \times _nC_2+...+n \times (n+1) \times _nC_n$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Find the sum

$1\times \;2\; {}^nC_1+\;2\times 3 \times {}^nC_2\;+\dots+\;n \times (n+1) \times {}^nC_n$

**My Approach**
I was using algebric approach to solve this question but encountered$
^{n-2}C_{-1}$
I have attached the pic of my solution.
[My approach to above question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGOls.jpg)

Comment: Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation and re-fromat your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please avoid the use of pictures. If you want help, show some effort and type your work.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider polynomial

$$x(1+x)^n=x\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{k}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^{k+1}\tag{1}$$

differentiate **twice** both extreme sides of (1) and set $x=1$.

Comment: Once more a courageous anonymous downvoter though 1) the OP has perfectly worked on his issue 2) The answer is correct under the form of a hint (I do not do all the work).

Answer (score 1):

The above sum is given as
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)^n\binom{n}{r}
=\sum_{r=1}^n \left[r^2\binom{n}{r}+r\binom{n}{r}\right].$$
Using
$$(x+1)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n x^r\binom{n}{r},$$
differntiating both sides
$$n(x+1)^{n-1}=\sum_{r=0}^n rx^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}.$$
The term at $r=0$ would be zero itself, then
$$n(x+1)^{n-1}=\sum_{r=1}^n rx^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}. \tag{1}$$
At $x=1$
$$n(2)^{n-1}=\sum_{r=1}^n r\binom{n}{r} .\tag{2}$$
From eqn. $(1)$, multiplying both sides by $x$
$$nx(x+1)^{n-1}=\sum_{r=1}^n rx^{r}\binom{n}{r}.$$
Differentiating both sides
$$n(x+1)^{n-1}+n(n-1)x(x+1)^{n-2}=\sum_{r=1}^n r^2x^{r-1}\binom{n}{r}.$$
At $x=1$
$$n(2)^{n-1}+n(n-1)(2)^{n-2}=\sum_{r=1}^n r^2\binom{n}{r}. \tag{3}$$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$
\begin{align*}\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)\binom{n}{r} & = n(2)^{n-1}+n(n-1)(2)^{n-2} +n(2)^{n-1}\\ &
=n(2)^{n}+n(n-1)(2)^{n-2}.\end{align*}

Comment: It is better to use $\binom{n}{k}$ instead of ${}^n C_k$.

Comment: @Gary - thanks, I was unaware of that

Comment: You can use \cdot instead of . as well.

Comment: I see you have been downvoted like me for a good answer. This is discouraging...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question a while back.

When you have $r\binom{n}{r}$ while you sum $r$, applying the formula will result in a negative lower index. The point here is that we treat this term to be $0$, rather than undefined.

You can think of this intuitively as follows: Since there is no negative power term in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$, $\binom{n}{k}=0,k\in\mathbb{I^-}$

---

Edit: [Found](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988977/lower-index-of-binomial-coefficient-becoming-negative-upon-solving) it!! Check @JMoravitz's comment

Comment: There was a post on MSE on this very same thing. I couldnt find it right now, will update when I do

Comment: **Thank You @DatBoi**